# Can't figure out why list index out of range

Tags: python

I'm brand new to Python just trying to make a webscraper. I can't figure out why my index is saying list out of range when I have the variable set to 0 for the first index before I start building up the list.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def kijiji_spider(max_pages):
    page = 1
    while page <= max_pages:
        url = "http://www.kijiji.ca/b-cars-trucks/alberta/convertible__coupe__hatchback__other+body+type__sedan__wagon/page-" + str(page) + "/c174l9003a138?price=__5000"
        sourcecode = requests.get(url)
        plain_text = sourcecode.text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text)
        a = 0
        lista=[]
        for link in soup.find_all("a", {"class": "title"}):
            if a == 0:
                href = "|http://www.kijiji.ca" + link.get("href")
                lista.append(href)
            elif a != 0:
                href = "http://www.kijiji.ca" + link.get("href")
                lista.append(href)
            a += 1
        i = 0
        listb = []
        for link in soup.find_all("a", {"class": "title"}):
            title = link.string
            listb[i] = listb[i] + "|" + title.strip()
            i += 1
        x = 0
        listc = []
        for other in soup.find_all("td", {"class": "price"}):
            price = other.string
            listc[x] = listc[x] + "|" + price.strip()
            x += 1
        page += 1
        print(lista)
        print(listb)
        print(listc)

kijiji_spider(1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `listb` is empty, and then you are trying to access item `0` in it. Since its empty, there is nothing to access so you are getting the `IndexError` exception:

```
    i = 0
    listb = []
    for link in soup.find_all("a", {"class": "title"}):
        title = link.string
        listb[i] = listb[i] + "|" + title.strip()
        i += 1
```

I think what you want to do here is append to the values from the first list you created (`lista`), so you probably wanted `listb.append(lista[i] + '|' + title.split())`.

You don't need counters for lists in Python, you simply append to the list and it will grow automatically.

I am not sure why you are adding `|` before your URLs, but your entire code can be simplified to the following:

```
def kijiji_spider(max_pages):
    page = 1
    collected_urls = [] # store all URLs on each "run"
    while page <= max_pages:
        url = "http://www.kijiji.ca/b-cars-trucks/alberta/convertible__coupe__hatchback__other+body+type__sedan__wagon/page-" + str(page) + "/c174l9003a138?price=__5000"
        sourcecode = requests.get(url)
        plain_text = sourcecode.text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text)
        links = [i.get('href') for i in soup.find_all('a', {'class': 'title'})]
        titles = [i.string.strip() for i in soup.find_all('a', {'class': 'title'})]
        prices = [i.string.strip() for i in soup.find_all("td", {"class": "price"})]
        results = zip(links, titles, prices)
        collected_urls.append(results)
        page += 1


data = kijiji_spider(5)
for results in data:
    for link, title, price in results:
        print('http://www.kijiji.ca{} | {} | {}'.format(link, title, price))
```